# script for automatically loading reference files from different destinations in Maya

Tags: python, maya

Hi a beginner in writing python scripts for Maya. I am trying to write a script that automates the process of opening a Maya file along with its references. Usually when the parent file and reference files are in different destinations Maya cannot open a file being referenced and you have to browse the filename to open it. I am trying to automate this. When a user tries to open a file it should open with all its references. So far I have got this but the main part is what I am confused about.

```
import pymel.api as api

def callFunc():
    print "hello world" # just a print cmd to check

print "registering a file reference call back"
cb = api.MSceneMessage_addCallback(api.MSceneMessage.kAfterOpen, callFunc())

def callbackOff():
    api.MSceneMessage.removeCallback(cb)
```

So when the function callFunc() is called, this is where all the action happens. Now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: There is a built in mechanism for this in Maya its called **dirmap** which can automatically redirect the files form elsewhere. As a general rule its its a bit too late to do this if the reference us loaded without **dirmap** unless you suspend loading of references (which the user can override).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a specific reason to use pymel, I'd go with regular Maya commands:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os

def openFileAndRemapRefs():
    multipleFilters = "Maya Files (*.ma *.mb);;Maya ASCII (*.ma);;Maya Binary (*.mb);;All Files (*.*)"

    # Choose file to open
    filename = cmds.fileDialog2(fileFilter=multipleFilters, dialogStyle=2, fileMode=1)

    # Open file with no reference loaded
    cmds.file( filename[0], open=True, force=True );

    # Dir containing the references
    refDir = 'C:/References'

    # A list of any references found in the scene
    references = cmds.ls(type='reference')

    # For each reference found in scene, load it with the path leading up to it replaced
    for ref in references:
        refFilepath = cmds.referenceQuery(ref, f=True)
        refFilename = os.path.basename( refFilepath )       
        print 'Reference ' + ref + ' found at: ' + cmds.referenceQuery(ref, f=True)   
        cmds.file( os.path.join(refDir, refFilename), loadReference=ref, options='v=0;')

openFileAndRemapRefs()
```

For more options on `fileDialog2` and `file`, check out the Maya Python docs at http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/index.html

Comment: Thank you..but found another way to do it.

Comment: @zingy could you elaborate on what other way you found to solve this issue? :)

Comment: The solutions are mine and mine alone... until it breaks.